# When will the airing of Fairy Tail episode 176 begin?

Tags: fairy-tail

Will the series be aired again? If yes then when?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will come back, since there was this mystery person and all... Most say this year, sometime in April? It was just that there was a little problem with Lucy's voice character, but it will come airing someday! Hopefully. ^.^

Comment: Do you have any proof? And can you add what happened with Lucy's voice actor?

Comment: I really like this anime and I want to ask you, are sure it will be come back?
Thanks (;

Comment: Yes, its definitely coming back!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about future events http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/800/2014-edition-how-should-we-treat-questions-regarding-future-unannounced-events

Comment: @kuwaly She got caught in a huge scandal in Japan, she was fired from her agency. she been recruited by another agency now. and currently they are letting it settle a bit. I believe it was something like Sharing the bed with 3 of her band members, and it got posted online aswell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely starting. It was on a hault because the anime had nearly caught up with the manga.
It will be coming anytime in 2014.
The dates hasn't been revealed yet.
[This article](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2013/07/11/fairy-tail-anime-set-to-return) from Crunchyroll has information about the return.

So Fairy Tail is definitely returning with advanced animation and some more suspense :P
----UPDATE----

> This year's 13th issue of Kodansha's Weekly Shōnen Magazine announced
>   on Wednesday that the new anime adaptation of Hiro Mashima's manga
>   Fairy Tail will premiere in Japan on April 5. New episodes will air on
>   6 TV Tokyo networks every Saturday at 10:30 a.m.
>   [Source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-02-28/new-fairy-tail-tv-anime-slated-for-april-5)

Answer (score 7):

Since yesterday (2013-12-28) when the newest chapter in the manga was released, there was apparently a page which indicated that the anime will start airing again in April 2014. [[Source]](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-12-28/fairy-tail-anime-restarts-in-april)

[image]